# Questions when doing Mkyong's File attachment using MTOM example

Tags: web-services, deployment, jax-ws, containers, mtom

Hi I am following [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-attachment-with-mtom/). Although it runs well on localhost, I failed to deploy it in a real server. The error is `NullPointerException` in the line in the client

```
 Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
 ImageServer imageServer = service.getPort(ImageServer.class);
 Image image = imageServer.downloadImage("rss.png");  // NullPointerException
```

I can access the wsdl, but why does that happen? Do I need to have a container like Tomcat to do the trick?

One more question, why it had to be `Image`? I tried replacing Image with `FileInputStream` but it seems that files created by `wsimport` does not understand what `FileInputStream` is?

Comment: What is the application server?

Comment: The server is Tomcat 7